# RTTI GetFields and GetAttributes on TForm

Tags: delphi, rtti, tform

I have a `TForm` like this:

```
TMyForm = class (TForm)
  [MyAttr('Data')] 
  edit1: TEdit;
private
 FData: String;
end
```

When I try to get the fields of this form via RTTI, I only get the `edit1` field, not `FDATA`, and when I query for `edit1` field attributes I get an empty array.

For another class that does not inherit `TForm`, all works ok. Why?

Edit for sample:

```
type


{$RTTI EXPLICIT FIELDS([vcPrivate,vcProtected, vcPublic])}
  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    [TCustomAttribute]
    Button1: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    [TCustomAttribute]
    FData: String;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form3: TForm3;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  LCtx: TRttiContext;
  LField: TRttiField;
  LAttr: TCustomAttribute;
begin
  for LField in LCtx.GetType(Self.ClassInfo).GetDeclaredFields do
  begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add(lField.Name);
      for LAttr in LField.GetAttributes do
        Memo1.Lines.Add(#9+LAttr.ClassName);

  end;
end;

end.
```

Result where `Button1` is clicked:

```
FData
    TCustomAttribute
Button1
Memo1
```

Comment: Which version of delphi are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There could be a `$RTTI` directive somewhere in your project that's causing extended RTTI to not work.

Try adding the following just before the declaration of TMyForm:

```
{$RTTI EXPLICIT
  METHODS(DefaultMethodRttiVisibility)
  FIELDS(DefaultFieldRttiVisibility)
  PROPERTIES(DefaultPropertyRttiVisibility)}
```

This will reset RTTI generation for everything declared after it, and you should get proper RTTI after that point.

Comment: Thanks. I try {$RTTI EXPLICIT FIELDS([vcPrivate,vcProtected, vcPublic])} and I get the private FData field. If I put an Attribute in FData, I get it, but I don't get the edit1 attribute. ¿any idea?

Comment: @user1658625: With the information I have available at the moment, nothing.  Can you post the code you're using to get the attributes? That might help...

Comment: @jlra: Your `$RTTI` directive encompasses private, protected, and public, but items in the top section (added by the form designer) are `published`, which you didn't include.  Add that (or just use `DefaultFieldRttiVisibility`) and it should work.

Comment: Thanks you!!! It work now. Although I don't understand how without this directive I get edit1 when I call GetDeclaredFields

Comment: @jlra: Because `published` members have (some) RTTI anyway.  That's what `published` was introduced for: it declares members with old-style RTTI, which was used for form streaming. (That's why the form designer puts everything in that section.)